# How do I generate `.generated.h` files in unreal manually on linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, unreal-engine4

When I try to open the project, it says "The following modules are missing or built with a different editor version: <project name> Would you like to rebuild them now? If I click yes it says "<project name> could not be compiled. Try rebuilding from source manually." and quits. This is a new project, has not yet been opened due to this error. (I have tried several times with different templates)

So after researching I tried building manually with `GenerateProjectFiles.sh -cmakefile -game -project <project file>`, then `cmake`, then `make`. At first this didn't work because it was using g++ instead of clang, so I changed it to clang, changed the standard to c++14, and  now it almost compiles, but it complains that the `.generated.h` files do not exist. How do I generate them considering I can't open the editor, don't have Visual Studio, and am working on Linux? I also can't change the install files because I don't have permission (work computer).

GenerateProjectFiles.sh output:

```
Setting up Unreal Engine 4 project files...

chmod: changing permissions of bin/mcs: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of bin/xbuild: Operation not permitted
Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
<unreal dir>/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Linux/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Access to the path "<unreal dir>/Engine/Source/Programs/DotNETCommon/DotNETUtilities/obj/Development/DotNETUtilities.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt" is denied.  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0019e] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options, System.String msgPath, System.Boolean bFromProxy, System.Boolean useLongPath, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00000] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions,string,bool,bool,bool)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile (System.String path, System.Boolean append, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x0001c] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00055] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean append) [0x00008] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(string,bool)
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteLinesToFile.Execute () [0x0002e] in <1e06a39ffa2a4ecc9361f5e710a0e7cb>:0 
<unreal dir>/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Linux/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Access to the path "<unreal dir>/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/obj/Development/UnrealBuildTool.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt" is denied.  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0019e] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options, System.String msgPath, System.Boolean bFromProxy, System.Boolean useLongPath, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00000] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions,string,bool,bool,bool)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile (System.String path, System.Boolean append, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x0001c] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00055] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean append) [0x00008] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(string,bool)
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteLinesToFile.Execute () [0x0002e] in <1e06a39ffa2a4ecc9361f5e710a0e7cb>:0 
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
```

make error:

```
    In file included from <project dir>/Source/MyProject2/MyProject2GameMode.cpp:3:
    <project dir>/Source/MyProject2/MyProject2GameMode.h:7:10: fatal error: 
          'MyProject2GameMode.generated.h' file not found
    #include "MyProject2GameMode.generated.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    118 warnings and 1 error generated.
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/FakeTarget.dir/Source/MyProject2/MyProject2GameMode.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/FakeTarget.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I don't follow "I also can't change the install files because I don't have permission (work computer)."  At first I supposed you meant that you can't install or modify *system* files, which is not unusual, but the `GenerateProjectFiles.sh` output suggests that you cannot change the project source files, which is unusual indeed.  You ought to have your own copy of the sources, which you therefore do (or can) have permission to modify, and indeed it looks like `GenerateProjectFiles.sh` depends on that.

Comment: Unreal is installed on the system, so anything under the <unreal dir> is a system file, and I can't modify it. I'm not trying to build unreal, but an unreal project if that was unclear.

Comment: The problem was that the script didn't have permission to write to the log files, which it didn't like for some reason